# Mediaqueries behavior in zoom events

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, zooming, media-queries

### Preludes (and nocturnes)

I'm making a responsive website. One of the principal requirements is that the webpage should not have horizontal scroll at any resolutions until 800px wide. Also, shouldn't have scroll in any level of zoom, until 200%. The "biggest" we can see the page is in 800px with 200% zoom.

I'm using Mediaqueries for accomodating contents. Mediaqueries also detect zoom changes, so, in the case 800px with 200% zoom, it applies the `max-width: 400px` rules.

To make Mediaqueries work in older IE versions (client wants since IE7) I'm using [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). It works fine.

### New details in the problem:

While FF, CH and other decent browsers, detect the **zoom event** and apply the Mediaqueries properly, IE (or Respond.js) don't. If I zoom 200% in IE, Mediaqueries don't apply until I refresh the page.

In my localhost, it works fine (apply the mediaqueries both in zoom and resize events.)

I have debuged the code to break in this line:

```
//adjust on resize
    function callMedia(){
        applyMedia( true );   /* <---- THAT--- */
    }
    if( win.addEventListener ){
        win.addEventListener( "resize", callMedia, false );
    }
    else if( win.attachEvent ){
        win.attachEvent( "onresize", callMedia );
    }
```

**In localhost**, it stops when I'm trying to resize the windows even when I zoom (ctrl + "+" or ctrl + mousewheel or "Page" menu).

**At server**, doesn't stop at zoom, only at resize.

---

Why it isn't working? I haven't skills in back-end programming, and I think there's no problem with the js code (?)... it seems it's something in *the back* (I can't explain properly), but what could be for?

**Already tried:**

- We can't force auto refresh in zoom events (client requirements).
- I have tried css3-mediaqueries.js, but I can't make it work, (and also it's too heavy for my webpage).
- I have disabled all the other JS in the Web Portal (thinking perhaps some JS is bothering Respond), but still no results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried adding a benign call to redraw the page?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand so much... (never have heard from "benign call" :$ ). It's like a refresh or something? A quick search in Google delivers me "refresh tutorials", but as I said we can't do that....

Comment: Sure no problem. Basically various manipulations of DOM elements can cause the browser to "redraw" the dom. Like anything there are some version / render agent issues you would need to familiarize yourself on - but a simple one is triggering the window.resize method. I'm not 100% familiar with Respond.js so this is more of a test suggestion than a clear answer - but in essence what you need to do is trigger the browser to redraw.

Comment: At least this point me in some direction to start testing, thank you very much for your suggestion! I'll try :)

Comment: Not sure about respond.js, but do you want scroll at all? I always set a max-width of 98% (or similar) to prevent content spreading beyond the viewport sides.

Comment: @ralph.m I already do, but this page it's very complicated (it's a huge web portal) and we use a CMS (I don't always have the control of the html)  and sometimes contents stack over other contents, you know... little details I must fix ;)